# Italian residence permit renewal

Tags: residency

I have a valid student residence permit in Italy, which will expire in two weeks. Ideally, I am supposed to apply for renewal a month before expiry. The issue in Milan is that when I go to the post office for the renewal application of the residence permit, they tell me that the application kits/forms are finished and they will receive the new ones next week. This has been happening for the last two weeks and I have been to four, five different post offices (major ones in Milan) but I got the same answer.

What should I do in this situation? If I'm unable to submit the application before the expiry of my current residence permit (two weeks from now), will I be allowed to live in Italy on the basis that it was not my fault? What are the options?

Please also note that I'm a non-EU student, from Pakistan.

Comment: I think you might be better on the Expatriates site as this does not seem to be about travel.

Comment: I think you should go to the Questura (Police station) and try to apply the renewal there by yourself without the need to use the postal service before your residency permit expires.

Comment: I agree Questura is the place to go. They have the immigration office and manage residence permits.